# How to use OS video controls for react-native-video?

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

Is there any way to use the built in iOS/Android video controls for video playback in React Native?

For example, here is what it would look like on iOS

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `expo-av` library to do this. You can also use this library in bare project as well. (https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-av)

All you need to do to get the native video controls is pass in `useNativeControls`. Heres there code and example (https://snack.expo.dev/@heytony01/video)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Video, AVPlaybackStatus } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {
  const video = React.useRef(null);
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Video
        ref={video}
        style={styles.video}
        source={{
          uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        }}
        useNativeControls
        resizeMode="contain"
        isLooping
        onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
      />
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <Button
          title={status.isPlaying ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
          onPress={() =>
            status.isPlaying ? video.current.pauseAsync() : video.current.playAsync()
          }
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```